# Anyone tried using Scalatra application in cloudfoundry

Tags: web-applications, scala, cloud, cloud-hosting

I would like to know any one has ever tried deploying scalatra + 
scalate + ssp based web app in cloudfoundry. If so how did u managed 
to deoploy with precompiled templates. 
Please let me know if you have any points or citations.

Comment: ya i have finally succeeded in this ....

Comment: Hi dude can you share you experience on this. I am also writing a scalatra service and looking to upload it in cloudfoundry. It would be really helpful. cheers...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't deployed to cloudfoundry.

But we did write a precompiler plugin for sbt-0.10. Well it's not exactly a precompiler it's a source generator, we use this to deploy scalatra applications to EC2 and the deployed war/jar doesn't need to compile the templates anymore.

https://github.com/mojolly/xsbt-scalate-generate

in case the link doesn't work.
The source is on github.
the github user is mojolly
the project is xsbt-scalate-generate